# How to solve this rational equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, rational-functions

I'm stuck on this rational expression. I factored and simplified, by what do I do next? Should I divide x/2x and 8/4?

I posted my work below.

Thank you!

[image: My work so far]

Comment: You're done! You could, if you want, factor out the $2$ from the denominator, like this: $$\dfrac{x+8}{2(x + 2)}\tag{iii} $$ But what you've arrived at (iii) is fine.

Comment: Looks good to me.
$$\frac{2x^2+12x-32}{4x^2-16} = \frac{x+8}{2x+4}.$$
You could say
$$\frac{x+8}{2x+4} = \frac12\frac{x+8}{x+2} = \frac12\frac{(x+2)+6}{x+2} =\frac12\left(\frac{x+2}{x+2}+\frac{6}{x+2}\right) = \frac12 + \frac{3}{x+2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's as much as it can be simplified unless you wish to factor out a 2 in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Since the numerator and denominator share no common factors, that is as far as you can simplify. $\frac{x+8}{2x+4}$ is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is it with additional constraints $x\not=\pm2$,also
$$\frac{x+8}{2x+4}\not=\frac{x}{2x}+\frac{8}{4}$$